# On Checkbox click event, Unable to remove checked="checked' attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Jquery Dialog box within my view, In this dialog box there is a UL LI list which is transformed to a treeview.   I retain previous checkbox checked selection by adding the checked attribute in my HTML Text Writer helper.  What I am trying to do is to remove the checked attribute once its un-checked. I am able to fire the event and get the value for instance true or false for check or uncheck but I am not able to scuccessfully remove the checked attribute if it was checked. The DOM still have the previous state of checked.

**HTML Writer**

```
InUl(() => locations.ForEach(location => InLi(() =>
            {

                var children = this.childrenRenderer(location);

                bool childStatus = !(children != null && children.Count() > 0);
                if (childStatus)
                {

                    writer.AddAttribute("type", "checkbox");
                    writer.AddAttribute("value", urlRenderer(location));
                    writer.AddAttribute("id", htmlPrefix + urlRenderer(location));
                    writer.AddAttribute("onclick", "handleClick(this)");
                    if (keys != null)
                    {
                        if (keys.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(urlRenderer(location))))
                        {
                            writer.AddAttribute("checked", "checked");
                        }
                    }
                    writer.RenderBeginTag("input");
                }
                writer.Write(locationRenderer(location));
                if (childStatus)
                {
                    writer.RenderEndTag();
                }
                RenderLocations(children);
            })));
```

**JS Function**

```
   function handleClick(e) {
        alert("Click, new value = " + e.checked);
        var $this = $(this);
        if (e.checked = false) {
            $this.removeAttr('checked');
        }
    }
```

If I uncheck a checkbox, the following function still gives the old checkbox which is now unchecked:

```
$("#errorCodes input:checkbox:checked").each(function () {
                        var v = $(this).val();
                        a.push(v);
                        if (errorTextArea.length > 0) {
                            errorTextArea = errorTextArea + " | ";
                        }
                        errorTextArea = errorTextArea + v;
                    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function handleClick(e) {
        alert("Click, new value = " + e.target.checked);
        if (e.target.checked == false) {
            e.target.removeAttr('checked');
    }
}
```

Comment: if I do that then I am getting an error 'target.checked' is null or not an object

Comment: And if you use e.removeAttr instead of e.target?

Comment: var checkbox = document.getElementById(e.id);
checkbox.removeAttribute('checked');

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple error in your code:

```
if (e.checked = false)
```

should read

```
if (e.checked == false)
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction.  It still does not remove the checked attribute, because I uncheck and then in my function  where I try to get all checked boxes, I am still getting the old checked box